# How to interrupt a Python program which calls a shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a Python script which has a loop to execute a local shell script, and if I want to interrupt it when it is running I have to press CTRL+C the number of times remaining in the loop.

Are there any easier ways to shut it down?

Comment: `kill <PID>` from another command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the value returned after the script execution - it should be 2 if script was interrupted, in which case you should perhaps raise an exception to stop the execution:

```py
import os

for _ in range(10):
    status = os.system('sleep 1')
    if status == 2:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
```